# Cordova plugin geolocation not getting installed

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am developing an ionic 4 application. I want to add geolocation plugin and use "ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation" for the same. On executing the commandI get error

```
cordova.cmd plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! code E400
npm ERR! 400 Bad Request - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-plugin-geolocation

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-09-10T08_17_48_727Z-debug.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

    cordova.cmd plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Comment: try to reinstall npm or to update it ^^

Comment: I have the same error

Comment: re installation of npm solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use below commands from you ionic project directory

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
npm install @ionic-native/geolocation
```